# Expected exit times from intervals of diffusions using scale functions, speed measures and Green's function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, brownian-motion

To compute expected exit times from intervals of the form $(a,b)$ for one dimensional diffusions $X = (X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ started at $x \in (a,b)$, one can use that
$$
E \tau_{a,b}
=
\int_a^b G_{a,b}(x,y) m(dy)
\\
=
- \int_a^x \left( p(x) - p(y) \right) m(dy)
+ \frac{p(x) - p(a)}{p(b) - p(a)}
\int_a^b (p(b) - p(y)) m(dy),
$$
where $p(x)$ is the scale function and $m(x)$ is the speed measure of the diffusion $X$, and $\tau_{a,b} = \inf\{ t \geq 0 :\: X_t \notin (a,b) \}$, with Green's function being defined as
$$
G_{a,b}(x,y) 
= 
\frac
{( p(x \wedge y) - p(a) ) ( p(b) - p(x \vee y )}
{ p(b) - p(a) }.
$$
This is from [1] p. 343.

For example, if $X$ is a standard Brownian motion, then the above yields the well-known identity $E \tau_{a,b} = (b-x)(x-a)$. Here the scale function is $p(x) = x$ and the speed measure is $m(dx) = 2dx$.

I would like to use Green's function found in [2]. For the Brownian motion, using [2], p. 119, Green's function is
$$
G_\alpha(x,y) = w_\alpha^{-1} e^{- \sqrt{2 \alpha} x} e^{\sqrt{2 \alpha y}},
\qquad x \geq y,
$$
where $w_\alpha = 2 \sqrt{2 \alpha}$ is the Wronskian, and I can compute
$$
\int_a^b G_\alpha(x,y) m(dy)
= \frac
{\left( -e^{\sqrt{2 \alpha} a} + e^{\sqrt{2 \alpha} b} \right) e^{- \sqrt{2 \alpha} x}}
{2 \alpha},
$$
but this is not something I recognize.

> What is the relationship between Green's function in [1] (which yields the desired result) and Green's function in [2]? How may I use Green's function in [2] to compute $E \tau_{a,b}$ and what is the role of $\alpha$?

[1] Karatzas & Shreve: Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus (1998).

[2] Borodin & Salminen: Handbook of Brownian Motion Facts and Formulae (2002).

Edit:
According to John Dawkins, we should use the correct Green function below:
$$
G_\alpha(x,y)
= w_\alpha^{-1} \sinh ((b-x)\sqrt{2 \alpha}) \sinh ((y-a) \sqrt{2 \alpha}),
\qquad b > x \geq y  > a,
$$
where $w_\alpha = \sqrt{2 \alpha} \sinh((b-a) \sqrt{2 \alpha})$ is the Wronskian. Then we let
$$
G_0(x,y) := \lim_{\alpha \to 0} G_\alpha(x,y)
=
\frac{ab - ax - by + xy}{a-b}, \qquad b > x \geq y > a
$$ 
and compute
$$
\int_a^b 2 G_0(x,y) dy
= \frac{(b-x)(a-x)^2}{-(a-b)},
$$
which is not quite $(b-x)(x-a)$. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you have taken from [2] is for the $\alpha$-order Green function,  the density of the $\alpha$-resolvent with respect to $m$, for Brownian motion on all of $\Bbb R$.  What you want is the formula in [2], in the later section **6**, for "Brownian motion on $(a,b)$ killed at $a$ or $b$", on page 137 in the Second Edition. Let $\alpha$ go to $0$ in that formula and you'll get the same formula as in [1].

Comment: Hi @JohnDawkins, thank you for your help. I have made an edit following your input. Can you take a look at it? Where did I go wrong? Is it some computation error on my part?

Comment: My computattion of $G_0$ gives $(b-x)(y-a)/(b-a)$, $b>x\ge y > a$ by using the fact that $\sinh(u) = u + o(u^2)$ as $u\to 0$.

Comment: Hi again John, thank you for your patience and clearing up my confusion, I now get the desired result. Cheers!